# Django development environment with SimpleDB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

If I want to write a django app with Amazon SimpleDB, should I install a local SimpleDB server in my development environment? If so, is there a good one around? simpledb-dev seems to be no longer maintained. Or, should I access the DB on the cloud directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would access simpledb directly, just point to a different account or a different set of domains.

By the way, I don't think there are any "local SimpleDB" servers.  You would have to write your own test implementation which sounds like a nightmare, but then again maybe you have a lot of free time.

Also, you are probably going to want to actually get a feel for SimpleDB which will be easier if you are using the real thing.